# Why am I getting a "call to member function null" in my logs when file uploading?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm not sure why I'm getting `Call to a member function photos() on null` error in the logs with the current code in my controller.  I'm calling it correctly but for some reason, it can't read my `photos()` function.  I've tried many ways to fix this but to no avail and hit a wall I just can't climb over.

I've tried inside my controller but still getting the aforementioned error.

```
$user = $request->session()->get("user");
$request->$user->photos()->create([
       'file_path' => $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalName()
]);

return response()->json($user);
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my controller:

```
if(Auth::user()) {
        $request->user()->photos()->create([
            'file_path' => $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalName()
        ]);

        return response()->json($request->session()->get("user"));
    }
}
```

Here's my User model:

```
public function photos() {
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class,'user_id');
}
```

Here's my Photo model

```
protected $fillable = ['file_path'];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
```

Here's my migration table:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('file_path', 200);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("user_id");
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: `$request` has no property that matches the value of `$user`. You probably want `$request->user`, not `$request->$user`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `$request` object has a null value for `user`.  The code looks correct, and looks like it should be checking to see if there is an `Auth::user()`... but there is a weird gotcha that might be interfering.

I've seen times in logging where the `$request` object doesn't run a query to get the user.  Instead, it **may** have stale data. Whereas `Auth::user()` does query the database on every request, and thus you may have a non-null `user` in `Auth::user()`, but possibly nothing in the `$request` object.  Therefore, the if-check succeeds, but the call to `$request->user()` fails.

As a test, give this a try to see if it is any different:

```
if(Auth::user()) {
    Auth::user()->photos()->create([
        'file_path' => $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalName()
    ]);

    //etc -- see if it breaks here as well using Auth::user()
  }
}
```